# Image only on first page - Angular

Tags: html, angular, image

I am pretty new in Angular programming. I have a small Angular application. In my app.component.html I have:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>.
```

I want to have an image on the first page only (loaded on localhost:4200) as follows:

header
image
footer

I tried to set `<img src="../../assets/firstpageimage.png" height="500px" width="600px">` in app.component.html but then I have this image on all my components, after that.
The situation is absolutely the same with index.html.

Where do I have to set img tag in order to be only on the first..root page?

Comment: Yes, data in app.component will be shown globally. If you want it only in some specific page, you need to include the img in whatever is be shown in the router outlet.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to reliably determine what the "first page" would be, but it is whatever route or component is being shown initially in your router.

Comment: Thanks, @Rich! I updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the image in the component which corresponds to the root URL (`/`).

Comment: It is app.component. Because of that img is shown globally.

Comment: @littleFox I think you are misunderstanding how routing works here. When you defined your routes ("/", "/home", "/dashboard", "/reports", whatever), the contents of those routes are shown through the router-outlet. If you set a default route ("/") that leads to, say some homepage component, then that is where you should put your image. Think of app.component as your application root. The stuff in the root is shown everywhere. Whatever page of your app you are on, you will see the header and footer. That's why you don't want the img there, but in the home page route's component.

Comment: Since we don't know what your route definitions and component definitions are (they weren't provided), we can only guess at what that component would be, so it is impossible to give you a **specific** answer. If you don't have any routes defined (everything in your app is global in this case), then that is where you should look to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

My app.component.html is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <br/>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div style="text-align: center;" >
    <img src="../../assets/firstpageimg.png" height="500px" width="600px" *ngIf="(router.url==='/')">
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>


</div>
```